# How to get mouse position only in Qlabel? (for pyqt5)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

How to get mouse position only in Qlabel?
I want mouse position to start in qlabel.
So:
[qlabel loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BVV1.png)

my code

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    ret = self.hasMouseTracking()  # Back to mouse MouseTracking The state of
    self.ui.labelLOOPVIDEO.setText(' The mouse moved :%s' % ret)
    x = event.x()
    y = event.y()
    self.ui.labelLOOPVIDEO.setText(' mouse x coordinate ：%s  , mouse y coordinate ：%s' % (x, y))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what `self` represents in your case, but if it is the widget or window which contains the label, as I assume, then you can use this coordinate transformation:

```
labelPos = self.ui.labelLOOPVIDEO.mapFrom(self, event.pos())
x = labelPos.x()
y = labelPos.y()
```